# PyQT call QDialog form QMainWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I need to open some dialogs in my MainWidget application. When I call exec_() function dialog window appears but has nothing. I cannot even set up the title. Here some example of problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class prceditor(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('PRC Editor')
        self.resize(100,100)

class Glmainwnd(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Glmainwnd, self).__init__()
        # Resize Window
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.resize(screen.width()/2, screen.height()/2)
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)
        self.setWindowTitle('uniPRCsim')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icons/uniPRCsim.png'))
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        #Exit from APP
        exit = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))
        dlg = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'DLG', self)
        dlg.setShortcut('Ctrl+D')
        dlg.setStatusTip('Call Dlg')
        self.connect(dlg, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.mdlg)

        file = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        file.addAction(dlg)
        file.addSeparator()
        file.addAction(exit)

    def mdlg(self):
        p=prceditor(self)
        p.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Glmainwnd()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I call the same code for dialog from dialog widget it works. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is typo. You typed the overriden constructor of class prceditor with only one underscore after init instead of two underscores. The overriden version was never executed.